# Azure DevOps Pipeline - download build artifact not found when referenced

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

via azure devops pipeline stage, I'm, successfully, retrieving the build artifact I wanna deploy, but when referenced on the app add command, is not found.

```
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      displayName: Download SharePoint package (*.sppkg)
      inputs:
        buildType: current
        downloadPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
        downloadType: specific
```

Run Result:

*Downloaded Folder/SubFolder/solution-name.sppkg to
d:\a\1\a\Folder\SubFolder\solution-name.sppkg*

*Successfully downloaded
artifacts to d:\a\1\a*

```
- script: o365 spo app add --filePath "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\Folder\Subfolder\solution-name.sppkg" --appCatalogUrl ${{ parameters.o365_app_catalog_site_url }} --scope ${{ parameters.o365cli_app_catalog_scope }} --overwrite
  displayName: Upload SharePoint package to Site Collection App Catalog
```

Run Result:

Script contents:
*o365 spo app add --filePath "d:\a\1\a\Folder\SubFolder\solution-name.sppkg" --appCatalogUrl URL --scope sitecollection --overwrite*

*File 'd:\a\1\a\Folder\SubFolder\solution-name.sppkg' not found*

*Error: 404 FILE NOT FOUND*

*##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.*

Any clue why it cannot be found?

Comment: Try using `o365 spo app add --filePath "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\solution-name.sppkg" --appCatalogUrl ${{ parameters.o365_app_catalog_site_url }} --scope ${{ parameters.o365cli_app_catalog_scope }} --overwrite`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still got the 'not found' error.

Comment: Are you not using git repos for your pipelines?

Comment: I'm using azure git repos. (type: git)

Comment: Then why are you saving the sppkg solution to system directory? you can save it to build git repository and use it from there. Check this [video](http://bit.ly/pnp-devops-1). let me know if it helps.